# why 'CodeMirror.hint.anyword' doesn't work in react-codemirror

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, codemirror

editor.on("keydown", function (cm, event) {
      // console.log(CodeMirror)
      if (
        !(event.ctrlKey) &&
        (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) || 
        (event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122) || 
        (event.keyCode >= 46 && event.keyCode <= 57)
      ) {
          cm.showHint({hint: CodeMirror.hint.anyword,completeSingle: false});
      }
    });
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4thKV.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.on("keydown", function (cm, event) {
  // console.log(CodeMirror)
  if (
    !(event.ctrlKey) &&
    (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) || 
    (event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122) || 
    (event.keyCode >= 46 && event.keyCode <= 57)
  ) {
      cm.showHint({hint: CodeMirror.hint.anyword,completeSingle: false});
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjC1L.png)